# I need to figure out how to access data in a groovy map in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm a Groovy/Java noobie, I spend most of my time in C and golang.

In groovy (specifically in Jenkins using a pipeline), having this map (from println(mymap)):

`[data:[access-type:ObjectRead, access-uri:/path/to/something, id:some_id=:some_value, name:some_name, object-name:some_object_name, time-created:some_time, time-expires:some_other_time]]`

I want to assign access_uri directly to an environment variable.  I have tried several different things, i.e. `object.data.access_uri`, `object['data']['access_uri']`, `object['data':['access_uri']]`

Nothing seems to work.  Just a simple groovy nested map question.  I know all of the keys and types, so I don't need/want to recurse the map.  This is a bit frustrating since in my mind `myvar = object.data.access_uri` or at least `myvar = object['data']['access_id']` should work.

Comment: `access_uri` compared to `access-uri`? Is it just the underscore versus hyphen? I would expect `mymap['data']['access-uri']` to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `object.getAt("data").getAt("access_uri")`